# Change a list of list of str to list of list of int

Tags: string, list, csv, python-3.x

I am trying to read a CSV file and have the data come back as a list of list of ints. The CSV file is 6 columns wide and 2 rows.  Using Python 3.4.

It always comes out as a list of list of strs. Searching StackOverflow and Google shows 7 different ways to do this, none of which work. These are shown below the code as what I have tried.

```
import csv
b = []
with open('C:\Python34\DataforProgramstorun\\csv data6x2.csv') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader :
    b.append(row) # this gives me a list of list each element a csv str from print (b)

print (b)
```

The result is:

```
[['2', '5', '15', '17', '19', '20'], ['6', '8', '14', '18', '21', '30']]
```

I would like it to be:

```
[[2, 5, 15, 17, 19, 20], [6, 8, 14, 18, 21, 30]]
```

None of the following work:

1. `[ int(x) for y in b for x in y.split() ]  #builtins.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute  'split'`
2. `[int(x) for x in ' '.join(b).split ()]  #builtins.TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`
3. `import itertools as it; new =list(it.imap(int,b)) #builtins.AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imap'`
4. `for i in range (0,len(b)): b[i] = int (b[i])   #builtins.TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`
5. `results = b; results = [int(i) for i in results]  ##builtins.TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not'list'`
6. `b = list(map(int,b))     #builtins.TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`
7. `[int(i) for i in b]    #builtins.TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: On #3, Python 3 doesn't have `itertools.imap` because `map` is now an iterator. On most of the others, note that you need to apply them *to each list in `b`*, not to `b` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [['2', '5', '15', '17', '19', '20'], ['6', '8', '14', '18', '21', '30']]
>>> [[int(x) for x in inner] for inner in lst]
[[2, 5, 15, 17, 19, 20], [6, 8, 14, 18, 21, 30]]
```

The problem with all your tried solutions is that you only go one level deep. So you do consider the outer list, but then try to work with the inner list directly, which usually fails. To solve this, you need to actually work on the *inner* lists directly. You could also solve it like this:

```
for i, sublist in enumerate(b):
    b[i] = [int(x) for x in sublist]
```

And instead of `[int(x) for x in sublist]` you could also use one of the many other solution to convert all strings in a (sub)list to ints, for example `list(map(int, sublist))`.

Comment: Thanks, in addition to the solution, you also told me why my was not working.  thanks so much